# What's the best way to handle a file upload in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having trouble getting an asp.net MVC 3 app to bind to a class that includes an uploaded file.

Here's my class:

```
public class PhotoAndCaption : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFile ImageFile { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //make sure ImageFile is jpg image of proper size.
        yield return new ValidationResult("This shit ain't right!!!!");
    }
}
```

and here's the view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<p><input type="file" id="ImageFile" name="ImageFile" /></p>
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Caption)</p>
<p></p>
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
}
```

What happens is that the Caption binds correctly but the ImageFile does not. I'd like to bind it to a class that implements IValidatableObject so I can neatly validate the uploaded image to make sure it's the right pixel dimensions and such. If not, I want to respond with a meaningful error message. Ideally I'd like to do all of the validation for the class in one place, so I can check the caption and any other fields I might add later in one place.

When I test this my Caption property binds correctly but the ImageFile does not.

Comment: FYI, you can accept your own answer, if it was truly the resolution.

Answer (score 4):

> We have to use the HttpPostedFileBase class, rather than the
>   HttpPostedFile because every Request, Response, HttpContext and all
>   related ASP.NET intrinsic abstractions are one layer farther way in
>   ASP.NET MVC

This is Scott Hanselman's [MVC file upload example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) explanation, why we have to use HttpPostedFileBase instead of HttpPostedFile in MVC.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the ImageFile property from HttpPostedFile to HttpPostedFileBase and it now works.